# UItextField inside TableViewCell with more than one section - data duplicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitableview

I have a tableview to replicate a form page. It has two sections, with 8 cells in section 0 and other having 4 cells

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [tableViewSectionData count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
        return 8;
            break;
        case 1:
        return 4;
            break;
        default:
        return 0;
            break;
    }   
}
```

Some cells are used to show picker, which i have done by adding a button onto the textfield inside cell and enable then wherever necessary.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        TextFieldCell *cellInSection0 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TextFieldCellInSection0" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (!cellInSection0)
        {
            cellInSection0 = [[TextFieldCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TextFieldCellInSection0"];
        }

        cellInSection0.bottomButton.hidden = YES;

        cellInSection0.textFieldBottomLabel.alpha = 0.5;
        cellInSection0.textFieldImageView.alpha = 0.5;

        cellInSection0.textfield.delegate = self;
        cellInSection0.textfield.tag = indexPath.row;

        cellInSection0.pickerViewButton.hidden = YES;

        NSString *placeholderString;
        NSString *imageName;

        switch (indexPath.row)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                if (fname)
                {
                    cellInSection0.textfield.text = fname;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldBottomLabel.alpha = 1.0;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                }
                else
                {
                    placeholderString = @"FIRST NAME";
                }
                imageName = @"user";
            }
                break;
            case 1:
            {
                if (lname)
                {
                    cellInSection0.textfield.text = lname;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldBottomLabel.alpha = 1.0;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                }
                else
                {
                    placeholderString = @"LAST NAME";
                }
                imageName = @"user";
            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                if (address)
                {
                    cellInSection0.textfield.text = address;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldBottomLabel.alpha = 1.0;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                }
                else
                {
                    placeholderString = @"ADDRESS";
                }
                imageName = @"address";
            }
                break;
            case 3:
            {
                cellInSection0.textfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

                if (floor_unit)
                {
                    cellInSection0.textfield.text = floor_unit;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldBottomLabel.alpha = 1.0;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                }
                else
                {
                    placeholderString = @"FLOOR/UNIT";
                }
                imageName = @"address";
            }
                break;
            case 4:
            {
                cellInSection0.pickerViewButton.hidden = NO;
                cellInSection0.textfield.enabled = NO;

                cellInSection0.pickerViewButton.tag = indexPath.row;

                [cellInSection0.pickerViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showCountryPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                if (countryName)
                {
                    cellInSection0.textfield.text = countryName;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldBottomLabel.alpha = 1.0;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                    cellInSection0.textfield.alpha = 1.0;
                }
                else
                {
                    cellInSection0.textfield.text = @"COUNTRY";
                    cellInSection0.textfield.alpha = 0.5;
                }
                imageName = @"mapicon";
            }
                break;
            case 5:
            {
                cellInSection0.pickerViewButton.hidden = NO;
                cellInSection0.textfield.enabled = NO;

                cellInSection0.pickerViewButton.tag = indexPath.row;

                [cellInSection0.pickerViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showStatePicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                if (stateName)
                {
                    cellInSection0.textfield.text = stateName;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldBottomLabel.alpha = 1.0;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                    cellInSection0.textfield.alpha = 1.0;
                }
                else
                {
                    cellInSection0.textfield.text = @"STATE";
                    cellInSection0.textfield.alpha = 0.5;
                }
                imageName = @"mapicon";
            }
                break;
            case 6:
            {
                cellInSection0.pickerViewButton.hidden = NO;
                cellInSection0.textfield.enabled = NO;

                cellInSection0.pickerViewButton.tag = indexPath.row;

                [cellInSection0.pickerViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showCityPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                if (cityName)
                {
                    cellInSection0.textfield.text = cityName;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldBottomLabel.alpha = 1.0;
                    cellInSection0.textFieldImageView.alpha = 1.0;
                    cellInSection0.textfield.alpha = 1.0;
                }
                else
                {
                    cellInSection0.textfield.text = @"CITY";
                    cellInSection0.textfield.alpha = 0.5;
                }
                imageName = @"mapicon";
            }
                break;
            case 7:
            {
                placeholderString = @"ZIP";
                imageName = @"mapicon";
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (placeholderString)
        {
            NSAttributedString *placeHolder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:placeholderString attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor]}];

            cellInSection0.textfield.attributedPlaceholder = placeHolder;
        }

        cellInSection0.textFieldImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageName]];

        return cellInSection0;
    }
    else
    {
        TextFieldCell *cellInSection1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TextFieldCellInSection1" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (!cellInSection1)
        {
            cellInSection1 = [[TextFieldCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TextFieldCellInSection1"];
        }

        cellInSection1.bottomButton.hidden = YES;

        cellInSection1.textFieldBottomLabel.alpha = 0.5;
        cellInSection1.textFieldImageView.alpha = 0.5;

        cellInSection1.textfield.delegate = self;
        cellInSection1.textfield.tag = indexPath.row;

        NSString *placeholderString;
        NSString *imageName;

        switch (indexPath.row)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                if (cardNumber)
                {
                    cellInSection1.textfield.text = cardNumber;
                }
                else
                {
                    placeholderString = @"CARD NO.";
                }
                imageName = @"yearofincorporationicon";
            }
                break;
            case 1:
            {
                if (month)
                {
                    cellInSection1.textfield.text = month;
                }
                else
                {
                    placeholderString = @"MONTH";
                }
                imageName = @"calender";
            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                if (year)
                {
                    cellInSection1.textfield.text = year;
                }
                else
                {
                    placeholderString = @"YEAR";
                }

                imageName = @"calender";
            }
                break;
            case 3:
            {
                if (cvv)
                {
                    cellInSection1.textfield.text = cvv;
                }
                else
                {
                    placeholderString = @"CVV";
                }
                imageName = @"yearofincorporationicon";
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (placeholderString)
        {
            NSAttributedString *placeHolder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:placeholderString attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor]}];

            cellInSection1.textfield.attributedPlaceholder = placeHolder;
        }

        cellInSection1.textFieldImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageName]];

        return cellInSection1;
    }
}
```

This works good at first glance. but when i enter some text in textfield (say textfield first in section 0), textfield first of section 1 also shows the same text. this happens to every textfield. sometimes the placeholder strings are also mismatched. it happens so random i could not get where the problem lies.

Any help is great-full.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create on separate value which track your textfield value . and that initial value change in viewDidLoad

```
 var arrInitialValues: [Any] = ["", "", ""] // this array count should be same as datasource array count
```

**In cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  cell.txtfield.text = arrInitialValues[indexPath.row] as! String
}
```

Replace that value in delegate methood.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let buttonPosition = textField.convertPoint(CGPoint.zero, to: tblView)
    let indexPath: IndexPath? = tblView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    arrInitialValues[indexPath?.row] = textField.text  // or if you use model property then you can change that property here
}
```

**Note this is sample code you can modify as per you needs**

Comment: Okay. i have doubt in line `let indexPath: IndexPath? = tblView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    arrInitialValues[indexPath?.row] = textField.text`. i have two sections, how will the method `textFieldDidEndEditing` take my current textfield. tag to textfield can be only set as indexpath.row (not straight indexpath).

Comment: currently i'm making a cell object with `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0]` for section 0 only. and by this cell object grabbing the text from its textfield.

Comment: for example you have eight rows in first section then add eight initial value in array . then if in  another section you  have 3 rows then add new array with 3 initial value .

Answer (score 0):

This happens because cells are reused. This is a common problem if you are not setting the value of properties in the if-else conditions properly.

For instance in your first `switch` case `if` condition you are changing `textField` properties but not in the else condition.

Let's say for first cell `if` condition is met. Now let's say when the cell is reused it will go to else condition. But since the cell is reused it will reflect the changes done for the first cell in the if condition. Since `else` condition is not changing the `textField` properties you are getting the old values.

I am changing the `case 0` `if-else` condition.

```
    if (fname)
    {
         cellInSection0.textfield.text = fname;
         cellInSection0.textFieldBottomLabel.alpha = 1.0;
         cellInSection0.textFieldImageView.alpha = 1.0;
         placeholderString = @"ifPartPlaceHolderName";
    }
    else
    {
         cellInSection0.textfield.text = @"Else  part name";
         cellInSection0.textFieldBottomLabel.alpha = elsePartAlphaValue;
         cellInSection0.textFieldImageView.alpha = elsePartAlphaValue;
         placeholderString = @"FIRST NAME";
    }
```

You need to change the remaining cases too. Just remember that whatever cell property you change in `if` condition you have to give an alternative in the `else` part.

Comment: Thank you! this makes sense. i will your suggestion

Comment: No. it is overlapping existing text in textfield.